# bernoulli and binomial process

Tags: statistics

What are some examples of bernoulli processes that occur in the insurance field? I have thought about indicators but can someone please incorporate this into an example they've came across in real-world?

Answer (score 0):

A Bernoulli process is just a sequence of Bernoulli random variables. For instance, if I have monthly data on whether someone has been in a car accident, I could model it using a Bernoulli process: I assume that every month, a person can be involved in a car accident with probability $p$. Now, one of the things that's usually done in insurance is to check for scams. This amounts to looking whether the data you have actually conforms to a Bernoulli process, or if recently the person has been having many more accidents than what you'd expect by chance. You can also check whether there has been a spike in car accidents in people living in a given neighborhood because of a new traffic light; or whether neighborhoods which starting teaching driving classes actually reduce the number of accidents; or whether new drives are involved in more accidents than older drivers, etc.

Many other examples are possible, all involving indicator functions (at least in the examples I know). Since Bernoullis only take two values, they are essentially used to model two classes (alive vs dead, has a car vs not, young vs old, college educated vs not, etc.). A Bernoulli process is just keeping track of the changes within these classes as time moves on.